# How can I understand why in Jenkins job timeout was happened?

Tags: java, svn, jenkins

I am running Jenkins job and afterwards I am getting timeout error:

> get.hudson.release.version:
>
> get.svn.build.version:
>        [echo] Determinating build version
>        [echo] Check SVN info for URL: 
>        [svn]  started ... Build timed out (after 30 minutes). Marking the build as failed. Build was aborted Archiving artifacts

I've checked configuration of job. It looks fine. URL is working. I can get it via the browser. How can I investigate/understand the root cause of problem?

Comment: Did you try the url directly from the jenkins server e.g. via wget if you're on linux?

Comment: I think the problem doesn't join with URL. At the begging of the job I get successfully Checking out...URL which is working fine.